# calling .net 4 from .net 3.5 via self hosted wcf service

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, interop, migration

I have a .net 3.5 application. It cannot be migrated to 4.

I need to call a .net 4 assembly from my application.

I thought to create a new executable in .net 4 which has a self hosted wcf service that is an adapter over the 4 assembly. My 3.5 app can then execute the external process and call the assembly.

This is a little ugly - any better idea?

Comment: Ugly indeed, but I can't think of a better idea. Would love to know if it works, if you choose to implement this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google says it is possible. It seems there is a new feature in .Net 4 called Inproc Sxs (In process side by side).

Have a look here :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxgeneralprerelease/thread/6f699c4f-58f5-4f6f-8a8c-08482e5f4478
and here :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrteam/archive/2009/06/03/in-process-side-by-side-part1.aspx

Comment: +1 because I didn't know this! You will need a COM layer in between though (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxappcompatprerelease/thread/a181e9b0-9d67-4d3c-80c4-11529196d3bc)