# calling CLR4 code from CLR2

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

i am writing plugins for a dotnet 3.5 app, and thus my assembly needs to be CLR2. Is there a way that from inside my CLR2 code that i can load and host dotnet 4 and call dotnet 4 code?

Comment: Since you have both CLRv2 and CLRv4 in the same process, this should be possible somehow. Perhaps with a bit of native interop.

Comment: @CodeInChaos this is possible IF the main process were V4 but the OP has a main process running as V2 which does not support this (exception being out-of-process COM)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the sane answer is "You probably can't call .Net 4.0 directly... but you *can* interface with it."

In any of several ways.  Including COM,  Web Services or something called "Inproc Sxs":

[calling .net 4 from .net 3.5 via self hosted wcf service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646881/calling-net-4-from-net-3-5-via-self-hosted-wcf-service)

Bottom line:
Yes, but you'll need to wrap your .Net 4.0 functionality in an out-of-process server.

Answer (score 2):

As per comments [UPDATE]:

Basically the .NET runtime learned with V 4.0 to load multiple versions of the .NET runtime (for example V 2) side-by-side. BUT before V 4.0 there is no documented ".NET way" to do this...

IF you really need to do this:

Implement the .NET 4 part as an "out-of-process" COM-Server (or Webservice or use some other form of IPC like shared memory), then you can use it from .NET 2.

Comment: @jrummell I agree, made my answer more elaborate :-)

Comment: yeah i was hoping there was some sort of SHIM.. whether it invoked me doing some mixed native/managed C++\CLI along the way. I thought that maybe somebody may have trail blazed this path before.

Comment: @klumsy the COM way and other ways (like SOAP, shared memory etc.) has definitely been traveled and work fine...

Answer (score 0):

No, not without doing something crazy.

You could use preprocessor directives (i.e., `#if NET_1_1`) and multiple project files to build for multiple versions of .NET. Each project file would need to set a value for the version it targets.

Elmah does this in [a few places](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/search?q=#if&origq=#if&btnG=Search%20Trunk):

```
// All code in this file requires .NET Framework 2.0 or later.
#if !NET_1_1 && !NET_1_0

// ...

#endif // !NET_1_1 && !NET_1_0
```

This of course assumes you have access to the source code of the referenced .NET 4.0 assembly.

Comment: How would the preprocessor help to run V4 code from a V3.5 plugin which loaded from a V 2 process ?

Comment: I'm assuming the OP can recompile the V4 code, which may be a bad assumption.